# AngularJS maintain data on page transition with different URLs

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to understand how we can maintain the previous data when jump to another URL and come back again.

I have a single page application, let's say page1, where I have a search field and search result. There are come external links in the search data and if user clicks to that links, URL changes and user goes to different page. How can I maintain the same result data when the user wants to come back to the previous result page by hitting browser's back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all you need for a page to be displayed in a given state is part of its URL. Let's take your example:

1. Search page. Initially empty. URL = `/cars`
2. You fill the search form and press the search button. This navigates to URL `/cars?color=blue&year=2015`. Going to this URL changes the route, and the route searches the cars and displays them in the page.
3. You click on a car. This navigates to URL `/cars/12345`. Going to this URL changes the route, and the route loads the car 12345 and displays it in the page.
4. You press the back button. This navigates back to URL `/cars?color=blue&year=2015. Going to this URL changes the route, and the route searches the cars and display them in the page, again.

In short, your app should work the same way as if it was not a single-page app, and if the server used the URL to generate a HTML page dynamically.

Comment: I am going to try this. I am accepting your answer too, thank you JB.