# Query params persist after factory call Angular

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Is it possible to show the factory call in the browser's address bar?

For example, when I say,

```
$scope.bearFails = BearSettlement.getBearFails({
    filters: $scope.filters,
    checkbox_status: $scope.checkboxStatus
}, function(response) { .... });
```

I want to show this url in the address bar so that it can be saved and also helps in the back button functionality. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: "this url". Which url? If you want to change the URL, use $location.url(), or click a link, to navigate to another route, and call that service from that route. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638427/angularjs-maintain-data-on-page-transition-with-different-urls.

Comment: I mean the url which getBearFails maps to. It shows up in my network console and returns data and works as expected but I want to update the address browser with the filters. Like in the link, you provided, you say, `/cars?color=blue&year=2015'. How do I do that after a form submit?

Comment: Then do exactly as I said: use $location.url(), or click a link, to navigate to another route, and call that service from that route. Read the answer I linked to to get a more complete explanation.

Comment: I wanna do that without changing the state of the page. Is that possible? I tried using $location.search() but it reloads the controller. If I use 'reloadOnSearch: false', then the back button doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, with a good router like angular ui-router and sub-states. But before diving into that, I think you need to read and practice a bit more to understand the principle of routing, and how angular, and single-page apps in general, work.